# Invoke-expression on a previous script to add parameters to it from a csv

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I'm learning powershell only from few month, and I'have been asked to write a script that outsides my actual knowledge.
I have a script which work perfectly when I have to extract user from ONE AD group. My probleme here is that this script accept only one parameter and I have been asked this week to extract over 1000 groups...)

.\myscript.ps1 ADgroup

What I want to do :
1. I get an extract in CSV so I'd like to put in parameters all these groups to my script
2. I want to generate a file text of the result but I am not sure which is the best way to do that in this case.

So Here is my code

```
$grouplist=IMPORT-CSV C:\Myfile\Mytest\liste.csv
foreach ($group in $grouplist) {
    Invoke-Expression .\membre_group_AD_V2.ps1 $group
                                }
```

My CSV test had just to group to run my test, I get the same kind of error on each group

```
Invoke-Expression : Impossible de trouver un paramètre positionnel acceptant l'argument « @{grouplist=Administrators} ».

Au caractère C:\myfile\Mytest\script\dev\bouclage_membre_group_AD_V2.ps1:36 : 2
+     Invoke-Expression .\membre_group_AD_V2.ps1 $group
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument : (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingException    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
```

If required  I can try to translate this error. If you can help to improve my knowledge it could be great! Thank you for tanking time to read this.

Comment: Why do you use `Invoke-Expression` instead of just running the script with the parameter?

Comment: because I thought it was the correct way of running my script. I've just test without invoke-expression it prompt a other error, it seem to try to compare my group (may be my understanding of the message is wrong )

Comment: It might be helpful if you showed us a sample csv file, with just a few records in it.

Comment: I deleted my response.  It wasn't helpful.

Comment: Matt has shown me that it's possible to determine the structure of your CSV file from the error message you are getting, so it's not truly necessary to post the sample CSV that I asked for.

Comment: You need to understand what an import-csv looks like, if you don't already.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have a "grouplist" header in your CSV file. I assume it looks something like this:

```
"grouplist"
"Administrators"
"Other Group Name"
```

Now, when you use `Import-Csv`, all rows are read into an object with a single NoteProperty per column, named after the headers in the csv file.

So in your case, each object in `$grouplist` has a `grouplist` property that contains the name - this is the property value you want to pass as an argument to your script:

```
$grouplist=Import-Csv C:\Myfile\Mytest\liste.csv
foreach ($group in $grouplist) {
    .\membre_group_AD_V2.ps1 $group.grouplist
}
```

Assuming that the output from `membre_group_AD_V2.ps1` is already what you expect, use the `Out-File` cmdlet with `-Append` to write it to the same text file:

```
$grouplist=Import-Csv C:\Myfile\Mytest\liste.csv
$OutfilePath = "C:\Myfile\membre_group_out.txt"
foreach ($group in $grouplist) {
    .\membre_group_AD_V2.ps1 $group.grouplist | Out-File $OutfilePath -Append -Encoding utf8
}
```

If not, you'll have to show us the `membre_group_AD_V2.ps1` script

Comment: thanks for the out-file answer. Your right about my first script work like the way I want. I have only a problem the csv part as parameters

Comment: This answer is helpful.  Unfortunately, you are guessing about what the CSV header really looks like.  You are forced to guess because the real structure wasn't revealed in the OP.

Comment: @WalterMitty `$group` evaluating to `@{grouplist=Administrators}` in an argument context kinda gives it away, but yes, having a sample of OP's actual CSV file would help